# X11 forwarding doesn't work with multiple tmux sessions

Tags: linux, ssh, tmux, x11-forwarding

If I start a `tmux` session locally and leave it open, then ssh in remotely and start a **new** `tmux` session (not attaching to the old one, a brand spanking new session) X11 forwarding seems to break. I've tried [this](http://brainscraps.wikia.com/wiki/Extreme_Multitasking_with_tmux_and_PuTTY#X11_Forwarding_Issues) workaround for a similar issue with `screen` but to no avail...

The error message when I try to launch a GUI app (like `xeyes`) is something to the effect of `can't open display: wrong authentication`. I actually don't know what it is for sure because it seems like it's outputting a carriage return and overwriting part of the error message with a new one...

For now I just go through and manually close all the tmux sessions that I had started locally before starting my new remote session. Is there any way to get X11 forwarding working with mixed local/remote `tmux` sessions?

Comment: #tmuxnotideal Also my iterm click to move cursor doesn't work.

Answer (score 15):

Not 100% sure it'll work for you, but that link didn't work for me either and I just copied the DISPLAY variable from the initial terminal and wrote `export DISPLAY=${copied from outside tmux}` which worked fine - i.e.

```
log in ...
echo $DISPLAY # remember this
tmux a
export DISPLAY=${variable from memory}
```

the function from that link gave me a completely different DISPLAY which didn't work

Comment: Still failed due to "Wrong Authentication"

Comment: thanks, this allowed me to open pdfs from tmux with xdg-open file.pdf

Comment: Did you try `ssh -Y` instead of `ssh -X` ?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem. In my situation, setting `DISPLAY` wasn't enough. By default, some of the environment is set when starting the tmux server (when starting the first session), not just any new session. The following works for me, but I doubt it's optimal.

In `.tmux.conf`, make tmux remember the variables that you want to keep from the outside environment. I used ones that differed between locally using Gnome Terminal and remotely using Terminal.app. Some of them probably aren't necessary, but I'm not sure which. The `-g` flag might not be correct.

```
set -g update-environment "\
  CLUTTER_IM_MODULE \
  DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS \
  DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS \
  DEFAULTS_PATH \
  DESKTOP_AUTOSTART_ID \
  DESKTOP_SESSION \
  DISPLAY \
  GDMSESSION \
  GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID \
  GPG_AGENT_INFO \
  GTK_IM_MODULE \
  GTK_MODULES \
  SESSION_MANAGER \
  SSH_AGENT_PID \
  SSH_ASKPASS \
  SSH_AUTH_SOCK \
  SSH_CONNECTION \
  WINDOWID \
  WINDOWPATH \
  XAUTHORITY \
  XDG_CONFIG_DIRS \
  XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP \
  XDG_DATA_DIRS \
  XDG_MENU_PREFIX \
  XDG_RUNTIME_DIR \
  XDG_SEAT \
  XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP \
  XDG_SESSION_ID \
  XDG_SESSION_TYPE \
  XDG_VTNR \
  XMODIFIERS \
  "
```

Despite the name "update-environment", the setting doesn't seem to actually change the environment. You can, however, retrieve it using `tmux show-environment`. So I used it to update the environment in my `.zshrc`:

```
zshrc_restore_x11_vars()
{
  if [[ -z $TMUX ]]
  then
    return 0
  fi

  local tmux_env="$(tmux show-environment)"

  for var_line in ${(f)tmux_env}
  do
    if [[ $var_line == -[A-Za-z_]* ]]
    then
      local var=${var_line#-}
      unset $var

    elif [[ $var_line == [A-Za-z_]*'='* ]]
    then
      export $var_line

    fi
  done
}

precmd()
{
  zshrc_restore_x11_vars
}

preexec()
{
  zshrc_restore_x11_vars
}
```

Using `tmux show-environment -s` probably would have been better. But I didn't know about that until I re-read part of `man tmux` to write this answer.

Still, I have to detach and reattach sometimes, when using an existing session. Though it is much less annoying than before.

Full disclosure: The idea of using `tmux show-environment` in the`precmd` and `preexec` hooks wasn't my own, but I forget where I saw it. Thank you, to whoever wrote that, wherever you wrote it.

Comment: Worked for me without the shell script. Very pleased thank you.